# Can you output a DataFrame in a formatted way without iteration?

Tags: javascript, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, and I'd like to embed the data into a JavaScript visualization ([this one](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey) from Google Charts). In order to do this I want to embed the contents in an array.

```
[ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
[ 'B', 'X', 8 ]
```

The first column in `sip`. So I can map it, and the others, `dip` and `bytes`:

```
df["sip"].map(lambda st: "[ '" + str(st) + "', ") 
df["dip"].map(lambda st: "'" + str(st) + "', ") 
df["bytes"].map(lambda st: "'" + str(st) + "'], ")
```

Now I have the feeling that this is sub-optimal to say the least. I would need to iterate over the rows and for the 3 columns map the string like that, and concatenate the resulting string, and remove the last `,`.

Is there a smarter way to do that? I cannot imagine that I am the first one who needs a JavaScript array like this from Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first convert `DataFrame` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then convert to `list`:

```
print (df)
  sip dip  bytes
0   A   X      5
1   B   X      8

L = df.values.tolist()
print (L)
[['A', 'X', 5], ['B', 'X', 8]]

print (type(L))
<class 'list'>
```

Another way is [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
s = df.to_json(orient='values')

print (s)
[["A","X",5],["B","X",8]]

print (type(s))
<class 'str'>
```